# How to check for different kinds of scanner string splits

Tags: java, string, file, java.util.scanner

Suppose you have a text file containing three columns, with data in each column. Sometimes the columns are separated by spaces and sometimes they are separated by tabs, like so:

With spaces:

```
1 250 643
2 446 116
3 199 292
4 801 171
```

With tabs:

```
1   352500  371500
2   381500  374500
3   304000  384500
4   431000  394000
5   355000  404000
```

Suppose the latter two columns contain x and y coordinates and they are stored into some array of location objects `Location locations[]`, where `Location` has some constructor like `public Location(double x, double y)`. So we parse these coordinates and store them in the Location array like so:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("someFile.txt");
Location locations = new Location[numberOfRowsInFile];
int i = 0;
while(i < numerOfRowsInFile) {
    String line = s.nextLine();
    String[] coordinate = line.split("\t");
    locations[i++] = new Location(Double.parseDouble(coordinate[1]),Double.parseDouble(coordinate[2])); //Parse coordinates
}
```

Now here is my problem. On the line `String[] coordinate = line.split("\t");`, this works for text files when columns are separated by tabs, but not when columns are separated by spaces. In this case I would require `String[] coordinate = line.split(" ");`.

How can I check what separator is valid? Something like this:

```
if (line.validSplit() == "\t")
    String[] coordinate = line.split("\t");
else if (line.validSplit() == " ")
    String[] coordinate = line.split(" ");
```

Comment: Come on, just combine the two to `[ \t]` and be done with that. No need to make it more complicated than needed.

Comment: You could also use the scanner to read the integers directly. That way you do not need to parse lines.

Comment: Wouldn't `line.split("\\s+")` work?

Comment: @BlackPearl Yes that worked thank you. I have no idea what `"\\s+"` is though?

Comment: `\\s` indicates a space. `\\s+` indicates 1 or more spaces. I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `split()` uses a regex,

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("someFile.txt");
Location locations = new Location[numberOfRowsInFile];
int i = 0;
while(i < numerOfRowsInFile) {
    String line = s.nextLine();
    String[] coordinate = line.split("\\s+");
    locations[i++] = new Location(Double.parseDouble(coordinate[1]),Double.parseDouble(coordinate[2])); //Parse coordinates
}
```

`\\s+` => Split string by 1 or more spaces.